# How to remove unwanted items from a parse file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
import time as t
import re

List = ["A","AA","AAB"]
Time=t.localtime() # Sets variable Time to retrieve date/time info
Date2= ('%d-%d-%d  %dh:%dm:%dsec'%(Time[0],Time[1],Time[2],Time[3],Time[4],Time[5])) #formats time stamp
while True:
    for i in List:
        try: #allows elements to be called and if an error does the next step

            Data = json.dumps(getQuotes(i.lower()),indent=1) #retrieves Data from google finance
            regex = ('"LastTradePrice": "(.+?)",') #sets parse
            pattern = re.compile(regex) #compiles parse
            price = re.findall(pattern,Data) #retrieves parse
            print(i)
            print(price)
     except: #sets Error coding
            Error = (i + ' Failed to load on: ' + Date2)
            print (Error)
```

It will display the quote as: `['(number)']`.
I would like it to only display the number, which means removing the brackets and quotes.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
print(price)
```

into:

```
print(price[0])
```

prints this:

```
A
42.14
AA
10.13
AAB
0.110
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `type()` function to know the datatype, in your case `type(price)`
it the data type is list use `print(price[0])`

you will get the `output (number)`, for brecess you need to check google data and regex.